# Плавное появление всплывающего окна с акциями

Tags: javascript, всплывающее-окно

Всем привет, пытаюсь сделать открытие акции на сайте в виде всплывающего окна плавным, но не получается. Есть список акций в виде массива картинок, нажимая на него должно плавно появляться всплывающее окно во всю страницу. Если я загрузил страницу, нажимаю на акцию первый раз, она появляется плавно, затем я закрываю и открывая снова её или другую акцию, она не открывается плавно, только резко. Помогите плез, не могу понять в чём проблема)
[image: Сама строка акций(просто фотки кинул)]

```js
const salesLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.events-block__link');
const popupElement = document.querySelector('.popup-sales');
const buttonPopupClose = document.getElementById('popup__button-close');
if (buttonPopupClose) {
  buttonPopupClose.addEventListener('click', popupClose);
}

Array.from(salesLinks).map((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', showPopupWithSales);
});

function showPopupWithSales(e) {
  const element = e.target.closest('.events-block__link');
  const dateStartSales = element.querySelector('.dateStartSales').textContent;
  const dateFinishSales = element.querySelector('.dateFinishSales').textContent;
  const descriptionSales = element.querySelector('.descriptionSales').textContent;
  const imageSales = element.querySelector('.imageSales').src;
  const imagePopup = popupElement.querySelector('.popup__image');
  const descriptionPopup = popupElement.querySelector('.popup__description');
  const startSalesPopup = popupElement.querySelector('.popup__start-sales');
  imagePopup.src = imageSales;
  imagePopup.alt = "";
  descriptionPopup.textContent = descriptionSales;
  if (dateStartSales.length > 0) {
    startSalesPopup.textContent = "Акция действует с " + dateStartSales + " до " + dateFinishSales;
  }
  popupElement.style.display = "flex";
  popupElement.style.height = "auto";
  popupElement.style.opacity = 1;
  console.log(popupElement);

}

function popupClose() {
  popupElement.style.display = "none";
  popupElement.style.height = 0;
  popupElement.style.opacity = 0;
}
if (popupElement) {
  popupElement.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    if (!evt.target.closest('.popup__container')) {
      popupClose();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Извините, но чего не хватило, чтобы добавить разметку и стили в вопрос? Все телепаты сейчас на новогодних каникулах :)

Comment: К сожалению, проект не мой, просто такое задание пока обучаюсь, а доступ только к этому файлу есть

Comment: Собственно да, проблема была стилях, спасибо, @UModeL